# How to install Apache Tomcat in Fedora 20

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, fedora

I want to install Apache Tomcat in fedora 20.
I have try to install tomcat using below code

```
yum install tomcat.
```

Then, enable Tomcat on system startup:

```
systemctl enable tomcat
```

Command is executed properly, but when try `http://127.0.0.1:8080` it shows a blank page.

Can anyone tell me, how I have to configure tomcat to make it work properly?

Comment: The sample webapps and default root are not installed by default. Run `yum search tomcat` and see related packages; if you want the admin console, example webapps, docs, etc., they must be installed separately. E.g., `yum install tomcat-webapps`

Answer (score 2):

I recently got the same problem. And if you are used to yum but not used to install applications manually you can find below how I resolved the problem using yum:

```
# yum search tomcat

Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
tomcat-native.x86_64 : Tomcat native library
jglobus-ssl-proxies-tomcat.noarch : Globus Java - SSL and proxy certificate support for Tomcat
jspc-compiler-tomcat6.noarch : JSPC Compiler for Tomcat6
openwebbeans-tomcat7.noarch : Apache OpenWebBeans Tomcat 7 plugin
springframework-instrument-tomcat.noarch : Spring Instrument Tomcat Weaver
**tomcat-admin-webapps.noarch : The host-manager and manager web applications for Apache Tomcat**
tomcat-docs-webapp.noarch : The docs web application for Apache Tomcat
tomcat-javadoc.noarch : Javadoc generated documentation for Apache Tomcat
tomcat-jsp-2.2-api.noarch : Apache Tomcat JSP API implementation classes
tomcat-jsvc.noarch : Apache jsvc wrapper for Apache Tomcat as separate service
tomcat-lib.noarch : Libraries needed to run the Tomcat Web container
tomcat-servlet-3.0-api.noarch : Apache Tomcat Servlet API implementation classes
**tomcat-webapps.noarch : The ROOT and examples web applications for Apache Tomcat**
tomcatjss.noarch : JSSE implementation using JSS for Tomcat
pki-tps-tomcat.noarch : Certificate System - Token Processing Service
tomcat.noarch : Apache Servlet/JSP Engine, RI for Servlet 3.0/JSP 2.2 API
tomcat-el-2.2-api.noarch : Expression Language v1.0 API
```

Because I ran into this dependency conflict:

```
Error: tomcatjss conflicts with tomcat-native-1.1.30-1.fc20.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I run yum install with the skip-broken flag:

```
# yum install --skip-broken tomcat*
```

And now after

```
# service tomcat restart
```

the Tomcat start Page appears as expected.